# Java OSI Transport Layer

Tags: java, layer, transport, osi

I'm working on a project where I need to communicate with a device using the transport layer.  The network connection will be OSI/CLNS over IP.

I could be wrong, but I don't believe I can use sockets for this type of connection. I'm looking for examples on how to create an application that can communicate over the transport layer (either in Java or C++).

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

[OSI-Stack open source implementation](https://kode.poss.or.id/svn/atn/trunk/module_atn/)

Here you can find open source (for linux) implementation of complete OSI stack.
There is also application example there...

Comment: Here is one... also, library author have a blog where he write about the project (ATN): http://exodream.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

> ... *create an application* ...

I would say that the keyword here is application.
When you talk about creating an application you automatically talk about the Application layer of the OSI 7/5 layers model.
When developing an app that can communicate with another app on the network you will be using some protocols - some of them will be part of the application layer and some will be part of the transport, network, and line layer.

It's impossible to create an app-based only on the transport layer - because in order to move information along with the internet you need to have use of all the layers.

what you asking is equivalent of asking how to build a car that has ONLY wheels - no frame, no engine, no gear, no seat, no steering wheel.

I would recommend learning a little about the OSI Layers model in order to understand better this whole subject.

I would start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model